# How do i apply a border around media queries in html css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a border with all the columns inside it. If I use a `div` tag around all the elements it just makes a border around the heading please help. This is the code I used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <style type="text/css">

 </style>
 <body>
 <center>
  <h1>COFFEE,TEA,MILK</h1></center>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <h2>A. Coffee</h2>
  <hr>
  <ol type="a" > 
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   </ol> 
   <img src="coffee.png">
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <h2>i. Tea</h2>
    <hr>
    <ol type="i">
   <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>  <br>
   <img src="tea.jpg">
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <h2>1. Milk</h2>
    <hr>
   <ol type="1">
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
    </ol> <br><br>
    <img src="milk.png" style=" height: 210px ; width: 210px;">
     </div>
    </body>
   </html>`
```

What I want is:

[image]

Comment: you question is quite misleading. Media queries is nothing that you can see. Its a tool to apply different styles for different rules like screen size or landscape/portaite mode as example.

Comment: Could you post a snippet which shows your webpage, preferably with the div that you tried which only gave a partial border? The reason is that it appears that SCSS is forcing a pale border by setting !important so @AliShams solution does not work. I do not know why the important is used and we may have to resort e.g. to outline.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you want to wrap the columns in a div separate from the h3 title. To get the output you want from your picture this is the code to solve it:

```
<center>
  <h1>COFFEE,TEA,MILK</h1></center>
<div style="border: 2px solid black"> <- Add this here I did an inline style
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <h2>A. Coffee</h2>
  <hr>
  <ol type="a" > 
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   </ol> 
   <img src="#">
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <h2>i. Tea</h2>
    <hr>
    <ol type="i">
   <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>  <br>
   <img src="#">
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <h2>1. Milk</h2>
    <hr>
   <ol type="1">
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
    </ol> <br><br>
    <img src="#" style=" height: 210px ; width: 210px;">
     </div>
  </div>            <- Add closing here
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the question, border seems to be overruled by the SCSS - but did you get this to work when including bootstrap?

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work fine with Bootstrap. I tested it here: https://www.codeply.com/p?starter=Bootstrap%205